# Input в libgdx, почему не реагирует Actor Dot на прикосновение?

Tags: android-studio, libgdx, mobile-development

Имеется класс

```
  class ActorListener extends InputListener {
    @Override
    public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button){
    event.getListenerActor().setSize(140,140);
    }
}
```

и класс

```
    class Dot extends Actor {

            @Override
            public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha){
                batch.draw(dotimg, getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
            }
}
```

и метод, создающий точки:

```
public void initDots(){
        for (int n1=0; n1 < 9; n1++) {
            for (int n = 0; n < 16; n++) {

                dot = new Dot();
                dot.addListener(new ActorListener());
                dot.setSize(40, 40);
                dot.setPosition(120 + n * 120, 120 + n1 * 120);
                stage.addActor(dot);
            }
        }
    }
```

Почему при прикосновении пальца к точке, размер точки не изменяется, хотя в ActorListener я прописал, чтобы он изменялся??

Comment: а запуск в режиме дебаггера вам на для чего в среде разработки приделали?

Comment: бесполезно, пробовал. может я просто неправильно что-то написал, и вы скажете где именно, если сами, конечно же, знаете...

Comment: И что вам показал дебаг?  метод `touchUp` вызывается при касании?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может быть вы забыли написать

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
```

Comment: вы правы, благодарю

Comment: еще один вопрос, setSize работает, но почему setColor не меняет цвет точки?